# mat paginator loading all data to first page in mat table ANGULAR

Tags: c#, json, angular, pagination, angular-material

I am loading JSON data from backend asp.net core c# API to ANGULAR material table but the problem is that the whole 100 JSON rows data load to the first page I have set up the paginator like below:

```
<mat-paginator showFirstLastButtons [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

as you can see paginator should load the first 25 rows but it loads all 100 rows on the first page. Below is the method through which I am calling my ASP.NET CORE C# web API to get JSON data to the mat table.

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    dataSource : MatTableDataSource<BugsData>;
      selection = new SelectionModel<BugsData>(true, []);
      bugsData:any;
        ngOnInit(){
        this.spinner.show();
        this.http.get('https://localhost:44318/api/Bugs/ListofBugs?projectid='+this.route.snapshot.params['id']+'').subscribe(
            (data:any) => {
              if(data.message!=null){
                this.snackbar.open(data.message, '✖',{
                  duration:4000,
                  horizontalPosition:'center',
                  verticalPosition:'top'
                }),
                this.spinner.hide()
              }else{
                console.log(data);
                this.bugsData=data,
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<BugsData>(this.bugsData),
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort,
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator,
                this.spinner.hide()
              }
            }
          )
      
    
        }
        }
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: If anyone wants some more information about this question code then let me know I am available here and will reply as quick as I can.

Comment: Can you please update your html code that include mat-table and mat-paginator both.

Comment: You are assigning the whole response to dataSource. You should only assign the first (25 / 50 / 100) items of response to dataSource. When next page is triggered, then you need to override dataSource with next (25/ 50 /100 ) items. Paginator will not take responsibility of loading 'n' no. of items in table. You need to handle it by loading 'n' no. of items in table each time.

Comment: @MaruthiEranki how it is possible bro to assign the data to Datasource as you mentioned above????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like this

```
// directly create the datasource       
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<BugsData>();

constructor(){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
// this part MUST be done in afterviewinit
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

and in your subscribe you just do this :

```
this.dataSource.data = this.bugsData
```

Comment: I am trying this solution and then let you know what happened...

Comment: bro this solution is not working for me. it is giving me an error.

Comment: what error ? can you show your code ? because it's working in my projets

Comment: bro, I solved the error but still now it is loading all the rows on the first page

Comment: here is a working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-85ucqc?file=src/app/table-pagination-example.ts

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooo much bro for sharing this example. it has solved my whole problem. I was struggling with the solution for a week. but thank you so much again bro everything you provide me for my help... I am very happy now..

Comment: Why didn't you validate this answer? Doing the setTimeout is not a good solution

Comment: Sorry bro I don't know what happened. when I was approving your answer then my system becomes unresponsive and I think I approved your answer but mistakenly it was not yours. so now I correct it you can see it now your answer as an accepted answer. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

Verify if `this.paginator` is getting initialized before `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;`. I am assuming it might not be getting initialized due to conditions in the view.

Initializing `MatPaginator` and `MatSort` immediately after `MatTableDataSource` causes the problem if they aren't initialized.

Can you try initializing paginator and sort after some timeout that lets the view to initialize them.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<BugsData>(this.bugsData);

setTimeout(() => {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I have initialized both mat paginator and mat sort above but I did not include it in the question you can see the which I updated right now...

Comment: Thanks for participating in my question.